# Google Tag Manager Trigger for users who visit random 2 pages on a website

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager, preview, eventtrigger

I am trying to set a trigger that would be fired if users visit both page 1 and page 2 on a website. No matter which page they visit first, as long they visit both pages.

Example: Homepage URL: shop.orgalife.com

Page 1: shop.orgalife.com/collections/page_1
Page 2: shop.orgalife.com/collections/page_2

However, I tried to use trigger type "trigger group" with 2 child trigger page URL contain specific page_1 and page_2 (they are both on page URL) and it does not work.

Is there any way to configure a trigger that would fire successfully?

Thank you all

What is the best trigger type when we want to have more than 2 conditions (I watched many tests for scroll and timer at the same time and It always easily works but don't know why click event or page view event never work)

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest you can set an item in localstorage when user visit page1.

Then when user goes to page2. Check the localStorage is exist or not. If yes then fire your code.

2. You can check the `Referrer` in the page2. If the `Referrer` is page1 and it can fire the tag you want.

Comment: Hi Darrell, thanks very much for the suggestion. I am checking now

Comment: You could also do the same with a session cookie if you are, for whatever reason, against dropping it in localStorage.